# how to translate text files react (.md files)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

I'm using *react-i18next: "11.16.9"* for translating my react project . It works well for the .js and .jsx files . This is the format I'm using

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
<th>{t('constant.name')}</th>
```

I got stuck in a scenario where I have some html content inside a .md extension file , Which I later render in my react component using *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* .

```
---
path: "/404"
title: "404 - This page doesn't exist"
---


<section class="section section--gradient pb-0">
    <div class="container apis-content">
        <div class="documentation-links">
      This text needs to be translated
    </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

this is my 404.md file . Which I render like
`<div id="main" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t(content.html) }} />`

Since it is an .md file I couldn't use any import any constant or hooks or hoc . How can I use constant variables like the *{t('constant.name')}* inside the .md file ? any work around for this ? or am I missing anything ?

*FYI: I can't convert the .md files as react files since there are lot many and I'm running out of time*

Answer (score 1):

You could create a React hook that injects the translation by processing the HTML content using your own tag:

```js
function useHTMLTranslation() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const newT = React.useCallback(
    (html = "") => {
      let key = html; // fallback
      const regex = /(?<=\[TRANS\]).*(?=\[\/TRANS\])/g;
      
      // probably you need to adjust this if you want support multiple TRANS tags
      const capture = html.match(regex);
      if (capture.length > 0) {
        key = capture[0];
        return html.replace(`[TRANS]${key}[/TRANS]`, t(key));
      }
      return t(key);
    },
    [t]
  );

  return newT;
}
```

template:

```html
---
path: "/404"
title: "404 - This page doesn't exist"
---

<section class="section section--gradient pb-0">
  <div class="container apis-content">
    <div class="documentation-links">
      [TRANS]constant.name[/TRANS]
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

usage:

```
const { t } = useHTMLTranslation();
<div id="main" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t(content.html) }} />
```

Comment: yeah that was on of the work around I found , it make sense for this use case but other cases I have large templates so I need to replace and map lot of variables